# std::vector Как удалить первый элемент?

Tags: c++

Собственно, есть `std::vector`.

Вопрос: Как удалить первый элемент?

Comment: `items.erase(items.begin());`

Comment: После этого должен быть произведен сдвиг элементов влево
Первый элемент - нулевой, если рассматривать вектор как массив

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector v;

...

v.erase(v.begin());
```

Если, конечно, вектор не пустой :)